# BigQuery export to csv and load in R for huge tables

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have a 100GB table which I want to process in R. When I export it to csvs I get 500 csv files - when I read them in r into data tables and bind them - I get a huge data table which cann't be saved/loaded (even when I increase the memory of the virtual instance that the R is installed on). I wanted to try a different attitude - split the original table, export to R, then process each table seperately. The problem is that I din't want the split to "break" in the middle of some grouping. For example - my key variable is "visit", and each visit may have several rows. I don't want that there will be a visit which is broken into different sub-tables (beacuse all my processing in R is done using visit as the grouping variable of data table). what is the best way to do it? I tried to order the visit ids by time, to export only their names to a spearate csv etc. - all the order by trials are ended with an error (not enough resources). The table currently contains more than 100M rows, with 64 variables.

Comment: How about dumpling the data group-wise?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am not sure what exactly do you mean - how should I do this by group?

Comment: See Mikhail's answer, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: Extracting large datasets from BigQuery so you can process them in some other memory limited environment is a path to madness. The *whole point* of BigQuery is that it can handle the processing of large datasets without worrying about local processing or memory limitations. What you need is a way to get R to link directly to BigQuery so only the results of queries have to be passed back to R. Try things like [bigrquery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to try a different attitude - split the original table …
>   The problem is that I din't want the split to "break" in the middle of some grouping.

Below is how to identify batches such that rows for same visitid will be in the same batch
For each batch max and min visitid are identified so that you can then use them to extract only rows for those visitids between min and max values thus controlling size of your to be processed  data

**1** – **Batching by number of rows**
Replace 1000000 below with whatever you want batch size to be in terms of number of rows

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  batch, 
  SUM(size) AS size,
  COUNT(visitId) AS visitids_count,
  MIN(visitId) AS visitId_min,
  MAX(visitId) AS visitId_max
FROM (
  SELECT 
    visitId,
    size, 
    INTEGER(CEIL(total/1000000)) AS batch
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      visitId, 
      size, 
      SUM(size) OVER(ORDER BY visitId ) AS total
    FROM (
      SELECT visitId, COUNT(1) AS size
      FROM [yourproject:yourdataset.yourtable]
      GROUP BY visitId
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY batch
```

**2** – **Batching by bytes size of batch**
Replace 1000000000 below with whatever you want batch size to be in terms of bytes
And replace 123 below with eastimated average size of one row in bytes

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  batch, 
  SUM(size) AS size,
  COUNT(visitId) AS visitids_count,
  MIN(visitId) AS visitId_min,
  MAX(visitId) AS visitId_max
FROM (
  SELECT 
    visitId,
    size, 
    INTEGER(CEIL(total/1000000000)) AS batch
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      visitId, 
      size, 
      SUM(size) OVER(ORDER BY visitId ) AS total
    FROM (
      SELECT visitId, SUM(123) AS size
      FROM [yourproject:yourdataset.yourtable]
      GROUP BY visitId
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY batch
```

Above helps you to be prepared for proper splitting your original table using batches min and max values
Hope this help you to proceed further

*Note: above assumes normal distribution of rows for visitid and relatively big number of rows in table (like in your example), so batches will be reasonably evenly sized*

*Note 2: I realized I wrote it quickly in Legacy SQL , so below is version in Standard SQL in case if you want to [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) or already using it*

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  batch, 
  SUM(size) AS size,
  COUNT(visitId) AS visitids_count,
  MIN(visitId) AS visitId_min,
  MAX(visitId) AS visitId_max
FROM (
  SELECT 
    visitId,
    size, 
    CAST(CEIL(total/1000000) as INT64) AS batch
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      visitId, 
      size, 
      SUM(size) OVER(ORDER BY visitId ) AS total
    FROM (
      SELECT visitId, COUNT(1) AS size
      FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
      GROUP BY visitId
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY batch
```